# Regular Expressions in Notepad++ Remove duplicate letters from a word

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

In Notepad++ I want to find and Replace in following manner.

Let If a word is 'Book' 
Here is two 'o' in this Word. I want to remove one 'o'

After processing the word will be 'Bok'

Here is some examples

UFU > UF

sans > san

noob > nob

clock > clok

AABBCC > ABC

Or I can remove duplicate word one letter by one. Let first remove all duplicate 'a' then duplicate 'b' then... up to 'z'

like-

ABCDEEABCDDABB > ABCDEEBCDDBB > ABCDEECDD > ABCDEEDD > ABCDEE > ABCDE

Antidisestablishmentarianism > Antidisestblishmentrinism > Antidisestblishmntrinism > Antidsestblshmntrnsm > Antidsestblshmntrns > Antidsestblshmtrs > Antidsetblhmtr > Antidseblhmr

Comment: what's output for banana?

Comment: banana will be ban. Otherwise I can remove duplicate word one letter by one. Like first remove all duplicate 'a' then duplicate 'b' the...

Comment: and for cantaloupe!?

Comment: If you want to process 'cantaloupe' then it will be cantaloupe>cantloupe

Comment: I doubt if regex is the correct method to approach such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works `(\S*)([a-z])(\S*)(\2)(\S*)`
Replaced with `\1\2\3\5`
You need to iterate until all repetitions are consumed.

**Explanation**:
There are five capturing groups, each on each parenthesis pair. Three of them are `(\S*)` which means "no spaces" to keep expresion on word boundary. `([a-z])` matches one char, and `(\2)` matches the same one char. This capturing group `(\2)` is the 4th and is the unique that is out of the reconstruction expression, keeping out the duplicated char.

Comment: Work Smoothly. Thanks. I understand the find Regex but I don't understand the replace Regex

Comment: The replace text is not a regex, it is just "an expresion" where escaped numbers refer to capturing groups and literals can be present. (There is none in this case). No symbol has a special meaning here except the backslash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it all in one pass, there's no way, not with regex alone.  However, you can do it in multiple passes with just one regex:

```
((.)(?:(?!\2).)*)\2+
```

Replace with `$1` and keep doing so until the text stops changing.

This finds the first character that has one or more duplicates, and captures it and any following characters short of the duplicate in group #1.  Replacing the whole match with just group #1 effectively deletes the duplicate character (or characters, if `\2+` consumes more than one).

If you're working on text that contains more than one word, and want to change them all, you can use `\S` or `\w` instead of `.`, to ignore whitespace and/or punctuation.